# ASP.NET MVC: the table AspNetUserLogins doesn't remember data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The table AspNetUserlogins doesn't remember data. It is supposed to remember data for when a user registers by an external Login (like Facebook). I've implemented external login with facebook and I had some errors. Does anyone know which method/action and which instruction exactly is responsible for saving the data to this table? It probably is an action from the Account Controller.

Edit: I found it's the ExternalLoginConfirmation action in Account Controller. It gave me an error at the instruction:

```
result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
```

(must be the line that adds the user to the AspNetUserLogin table), which is why I put it in a try-catch block and it solved my problem, but I don't think it's being executed at all. It just doesn't give me the Validation error anymore. I think it has a problem because I am requesting more data from facebook, like the first name from the user. It changed something in the login info maybe, and it can't be added to the database. Or maybe because I added the field "Name" (for first name) to my user identity.

My Startup Auth class:

```cs
var x = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
x.Scope.Add("email");
x.AppId = "2737863089761791";
//x.Scope.Add("public_profile");
x.AppSecret = "";
x.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name";
x.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
{
    OnAuthenticated = async context =>
    {
        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
        foreach (var claim in context.User)
        {
            var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
            string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
            if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));

        }

    }
};

x.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(x);
```

(where I request some fields from facebook, like first name). I deleted the app secret.

My `ExternalLoginConfirmation` method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
        var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email , Name = model.Name};
        
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {

            try
            {
                var useraux = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(useraux.Id, info.Login);
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    Response.Write("Object: " + eve.Entry.Entity.ToString());
                    Response.Write(" " +
                        "");
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                        Response.Write(ve.ErrorMessage + "" +
                            "");
                    }
                }
                //throw;
            }

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //--
                //await StoreFacebookAuthToken(user);
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View(model);
}
```